# How to remove scrolling when mobile menu appears

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a mobile menu option when you click on the triple line logo. But when it appears, you still can scroll. Is it possible to have it where you can't scroll when you are in the menu? I tried position:fixed; but I couldn't get it to work. Let me know if you find a way to make that work, or if there is a different way. Thanks

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
  }
  
  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
  }
```

```css
  #md1{
    width:100%;
    height:63px;
    background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
  }
  body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }
  .bars{
  color:white;
  }
  .overlay {
    height: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .fixedPosition
  {
     position: fixed;
  }
  .overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    color:white;
  }
  .overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
    .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    }
  }
.footer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  height: 80px;
  top: 546px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footwords {
  padding-top: 32px;
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  position: relative;
  left: 6%;
}
  .dtp {
  display:none;
  }
  .leftimage {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 95%;
    height: 365px;
    top: 67px;
    float:left;
    left:2.5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="CSS/styleindex.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src='Javascript/index.js'></script>
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-168595753-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-168595753-1');
</script>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>
    Rom Fradkin
  </title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type='image/png' href="Images/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <div class='dtp'>
    <a class="active-menu" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="Pages/academics.html">Academics</a>
    <a class="link" href="Pages/projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="Pages/communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </div>
    <div id='md1'>
      <div class='md'>
        <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
          <div class="overlay-content">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <span class='bars' style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; </span>
        
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </header>
  <div class='section1'>
    <img class= 'leftimage' src="Images/frontback.jpg" alt="Missing File">
    <div class='HelloIm'>Hello, I'm</div>>
    <div class='romf'>Rin.</div>>
  </div>
  <div class='bio'>
      <img class = 'rndface' src="Images/rndface.png" alt="Missing File">
      <h1 class='topname'>
        Rkin
      </h1>
      <p class='school'>
        Nechool
      </p>
      <p class='interests'>
        Encience
      </p>
      <p class='location'>
        Chicnois
      </p>
      <p class='mail'>
        fril.com
      </p>
      <p class='num'>
        (8
      </p>
      <p>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.instagkin/" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.linkedin.com/inin-a3a9541a5/" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://github.in" class="fa fa-github"></a>
      </p>
      <p>
    </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think simple way for page not to be scroll-able when you open navigation is set style `overflow` of the `body` tag to `hidden`, and you close the navigation, just set it back to `auto` for being scroll-able again

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "hidden"; // add here
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "auto"; // add here
}
```

You can take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/jquery) for example.